# Different callbacks on FB like

Tags: javascript, facebook, dom-events, facebook-like

I have two FB like buttons on a page, one in the footer and one where the content is. They like different urls. The one in the footer likes the website, and the one on the content likes the content specific url. I want the callback for each like do different things. How do I do this? Right now I'm listening to `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create')` for both so both callbacks are executed regardless of which like button was clicked.

Sometimes the user would land on the content page (both like buttons are loaded), other times the user would navigate to it (footer like button loaded first). This is a single page application. I am not sure if these details matter.

I guess this wouldn't be specific to FB likes. Binding to twitter tweets would be similar. How do I workaround this?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an argument to edge.create callback, which is full like url -

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        if(response == 'http://ubuntu.com') alert('liked ubuntu.com');
        if(response == 'http://bing.com') alert('liked bing.com');
        if(response == 'http://google.com') alert('liked google.com');
    }
);
```

check full example on http://jsfiddle.net/mxXY2/1/

Comment: this worked for me but I think that your jsfiddle is incorrect as I don't see a FB.Event.subscribe anywhere. thanks.